# Tracking Memory Usage in Python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, profiler, psutil, tracemalloc

Python code:

```
def my_function():
    my_list = [i for i in range(1_000_000)]
    return my_list

my_list = my_function()
```

Memory usage reported by different libraries:

memory_profiler: 82MB

tracemalloc: 36MB

psutil: 3MB

why there is some much difference in the memory usages calculated by different libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `my_function()` creates a list with 1.000.000 integers, which will take up a significant amount of memory and the difference in memory it's because different memory profiling libraries use different methods to measure memory usage

`memory_profiler` uses a line-by-line memory profiler that calculates the memory usage of each line of code.

`tracemalloc` uses a lower-level approach to measure memory usage. It tracks memory allocations and deallocations directly from the Python interpreter, which can result in lower reported memory usage.

`psutil` uses system-level APIs to measure memory usage. It reports the memory usage of the entire process, including both Python objects and other system resources used by the process.